# Do I have to start over from scratch if I added a new device in iOS development?

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder

I've followed this [tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-2e7310a1136ab7c1811-7fee.html#community) once and was able to test and debug on my iPhone. Now I attached another iOS device I'd like to test on. I know I have to add the UUID of the new device at the Apple Provisioning Portal. I went ahead and added it successfully. Now that I have done that do I have to start over from step 1 or can I skip ahead a few steps?

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first step requiring your new UDID is step 7, you can skip to there.

The critical step being;

> c. Enter a profile name, select the iOS developer certificate, the App ID, and the UDIDs on which you want to install the application.

Comment: Thanks!!! There was an edit button next to the profile and that let me add the new devices.